# Docker installation error on windows

Tags: docker

I am trying to install Docker client on windows but when i start the installer i get the below pop up .

[image: Docker installation error]

Can someone please guide me what should the solution to this issue be.

I am using windows 7 enterprise, 64 bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't docker require win 10 pro? See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install

Comment: You should be using docker toolbox and not this

Answer (score 0):

Docker requires Windows 10. If you are using Windows 7, use Docker toolbox from the following location
https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/.
As you install the toolbox, automatically the VM virtual box also will get installed. Atleast, that is what happened to me.
After installation, my docker container did not start properly.
So, I uninstalled the VM virtual box, installed it again, then started the kitematic and it was all a great flow to see my docker up and running!
Couple of the links that helped me gain better understanding:
https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4066
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/291